# How to solve libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file without sudo

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use import tensorflow some error appeared.
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdJm.png)
Because I used it on the server, so there is no sudo permission.
How can I solve it?

Comment: `sudo` doesn't really have anything to do with it -- if you have the file, you can put it anywhere you *do* have write access to, add that location to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and there you are. (Similarly, a package manager like Nix that can compile and install software under your home directory could be used to build a whole new copy... but that's not really in-scope).

Comment: BTW, it's much more helpful to provide the error as text than an image link. Images can't be searched; they can't be copied-and-pasted; etc.